# Property 'flex'' does not exist on type

Tags: cordova, ionic4, ngx-datatable

Getting an error whenever I am trying to build my ionic4 application using cordova. When serving this application using **ionic serve** or if I compile it with just **npm run build** or even **ionic build cordova android** (without the --prod) I am not having any issues. however whenever I run:

```
ionic build cordova android --prod
```

I get the following error:

```
Property 'flex' does not exist on type 'Page'
an error occured while running sub process ng
```

i believe it is complaining about this:

```
 <ngx-datatable [headerHeight]="50"  [footerHeight]="100" [rows]="rows" class="bootstrap" [columnMode]="flex">
```

I have tried to do this:

```
 <ngx-datatable [headerHeight]="50"  [footerHeight]="100" [rows]="rows" class="bootstrap" [columnMode]="'flex'">
```

which compiles but it doesn't render my table table correctly.

with [columnMode]="flex" and not --prod
[image: with [columnMode]="flex" and not --prod]

with [columnMode]="'flex'" and --prod
[image: with [columnMode]="'flex'" and --prod]

Answer (score 0):

The second one is the correct one:

```
<ngx-datatable [headerHeight]="50"  [footerHeight]="100" [rows]="rows" class="bootstrap" [columnMode]="'flex'">
```

So you need to explain "doesn't render my table correctly" in more detail.

In my experience with ngx-datatable you have to set the heights of everything for it to display nice. Here is a snippet from a project where I'm using it:

```
<ngx-datatable #table class="material expandable striped" [rows]="rows" [rowClass]="getRowClass"
    [rowHeight]="'auto'" [headerHeight]="'auto'" [columnMode]="'flex'" [reorderable]="false"
    [messages]="messages">
```

Also if you are using classnames then make sure the snippet is put in the global.scss not in the page level scss file. Otherwise they can get caught up in the Angular style namespacing.

Comment: thanks for the response, i've updated my question with screenshots to explain the different render issue I am having with flex on a ngx datatable.